# How can I count data from a column being added in the same query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query setup for data verification that will join a few tables and auto-convert currencies from non-USD to USD.

```
SELECT c.Id, c.Currency
, cr.CPDealId, cr.UnderwriterId, cr.PlacedDate, cr.Fee, cr.FeeDue, cr.AllocatedFeeDue 
, f.Rate
, (CASE
    WHEN c.Currency <> 'USD'
        THEN (cr.FeeDue / f.Rate)
        ELSE (cr.FeeDue)        
END) AS 'TotalConverted'
FROM DB.DB.CPDeal c 
    INNER JOIN DB.DB.CPDealRate cr 
    ON (c.Id = cr.CPDealId)
    LEFT JOIN DB.DB.Fx f 
    ON (c.Currency = f.MainCurrency)
WHERE IssuerId = '1'
AND c.Date BETWEEN GETDATE()-90 AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY UnderwriterId DESC, PlacedDate DESC, Currency DESC;
```

The goal is to take the resulting 'Total Converted' column and SUM the data within for each row that has a matching value in the 'UnderwriterId' column.

```
(SELECT SUM('TotalConverted') AS 'UnderwriterTotal' FROM ??? GROUP BY UnderwriterId)
```

I was looking to add something along the lines of this when I realized I have no DB to point it to.

Can this be done? I feel like I've searched for ages, but I can't really figure out how to even search for a proper answer.

Comment: It isn't clear to me what your requirement is adding sample data and desired output would help clarify , also mysql does not have getdate function and the error message you see is not a mysql error message - are you using MSsql/t-sql/sql-server?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using subquery? I think this should work just fine

```
SELECT A.UnderwriterId, COUNT(A.TotalConverted) AS 'UnderwriterTotal' 
FROM
(SELECT c.Id, c.Currency
, cr.CPDealId, cr.UnderwriterId, cr.PlacedDate, cr.Fee, cr.FeeDue, cr.AllocatedFeeDue 
, f.Rate
, (CASE
    WHEN c.Currency <> 'USD'
        THEN (cr.FeeDue / f.Rate)
        ELSE (cr.FeeDue)        
END) AS TotalConverted
FROM DB.DB.CPDeal c 
    INNER JOIN DB.DB.CPDealRate cr 
    ON (c.Id = cr.CPDealId)
    LEFT JOIN DB.DB.Fx f 
    ON (c.Currency = f.MainCurrency)
WHERE IssuerId = '1'
AND c.Date BETWEEN GETDATE()-90 AND GETDATE()
ORDER BY UnderwriterId DESC, PlacedDate DESC, Currency DESC) A
GROUP BY A.UnderwriterId
;
```

Comment: It does not seem to like that.

```
SQL Error [156] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Error position: line: 18
```
This is the error I'm receiving. It looks like there might be a closed paren missing, but I am unsure of where to add it.

Comment: GROUP BY should come before ORDER BY. Flip the last two lines.

Comment: @tuxedobob the ORDER is in the subquery so it should be just fine

Comment: Whoops. You are correct. In that case, I believe the actual issue is that the subquery needs to be aliased as a table. Try: <subquery> AS t1 GROUP BY UnderwriterId.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem with the following window function:

```
SELECT t0.*
    , SUM(t0.TotalConverted) OVER(PARTITION BY t0.UnderwriterId) as 'UnderwriterTotal' 
FROM
(
SELECT c.Id, c.Currency
, cr.CPDealId, cr.UnderwriterId, cr.PlacedDate, cr.Fee, cr.AllocatedFeeDue AS 'TotalFeesDue'
, f.Rate
, (CASE
    WHEN c.Currency <> 'USD'
        THEN (cr.FeeDue / f.Rate)
        ELSE (cr.FeeDue)        
    END) AS TotalConverted
, u.Name 
FROM DB.DB.CPDeal c
    INNER JOIN DB.DB.CPDealRate cr
    ON (c.Id = cr.CPDealId)
    INNER JOIN DB.DB.Underwriter u  
    ON (u.Id = cr.UnderwriterId)
    LEFT JOIN DB.DB.Fx f
    ON (c.Currency = f.MainCurrency)
WHERE IssuerId = '1'
AND c.Date BETWEEN GETDATE()-90 AND GETDATE()
) t0
ORDER BY UnderwriterId DESC, PlacedDate DESC, Currency DESC;
```